# Inserting 1 Million records is taking too much time MYSQL

Tags: mysql, performance, bulkinsert

I have a simple table test with three column

```
id -> primary key (auto increment)
name -> varchar
age -> int
```

I am using a simple stored procedure to populate 1 Million  data in table.

```
drop PROCEDURE if  EXISTS big_data;
CREATE PROCEDURE big_data()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE i <= 10000000 DO
        INSERT INTO test(id, name, age) VALUES (i, 'name', 34);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;

CALL big_data();
```

Problem i am facing is inserting 1 million records is taking almost 6 to 7 hours with this simple schema. I want to know how to insert data fast ?
I donot want to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` query, I have not change any setting in my.ini file.

Simply want to know the reason of too much slow insert?

System Specification

```
    Mysql version 5.5.25a
    innodb_version =1.1.8
    System = 16GB RAM / 8 cores @ 2.70 GHz
```

Comment: Considering this is a very inefficient way to insert data, your DB is actually managing to insert a few hundreds of rows per second. It's not that bad. Considering most of the cores on the machine do no good with this sort of serial insertions (it's single threaded)... for short, it's slow because you're using the DB wrong.

Comment: I didn't get the point that you are using wrong DB @AssafLavie
and also advise me to insert data using efficient way?

Comment: Not the wrong db, but using the db the wrong way. Do batch inserts or LOAD DATA. That's what it's for.

Comment: If id is auto increment, why insert it at all?

Answer (score 2):

Inserting 100 rows at a time is 10 times as fast as 100 1-row `INSERTs`:

INSERT INTO foo (a, b, c)
       VALUES
       (1,2,3),
       (4,5,6), ...;

`LOAD DATA` is probably even faster.

Answer (score 1):

try to make your query as single string and then execute it at once

```
drop PROCEDURE if  EXISTS big_data;
CREATE PROCEDURE big_data()
BEGIN
    DECLARE total_count TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE i <= 10000000 DO
        SET total_count = total_count + '(' + i+ ', name, 34),';
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET total_count = TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM total_count);
    INSERT INTO test(id, name, age) VALUES ' + total_count;
END;
```

Comment: This is currently downvoted to -1, and I would like to know why. Is there a particular reason why this is a bad idea? I have a similar problem as the question submitter, and was thinking of trying something like this.

Comment: @MarkVerrey it's impossible to track who downvoted it, but you can always give it a +1 if it's helped you.